# Is snort capable of detecting any form of steganography?

Tags: snort

Is snort capable of detecting any form of network steganography? I found only how to detect the data size of the payload. Using the `dsize` parameter. However, it is easy to not exceed a certain size of data. I was wondering about some information hidden in headers for example.